# Powershell adds trailing white space when writing string with new-line-code to textfile

Tags: powershell, whitespace, exiftool

I'm on WINDOWS 10, using POWERSHELL 7.x.

I want to write to an argsfile (simple text-file), that controls EXIFTOOL-operations. Each EXIFTOOL-command has to be placed in a separate line. Writing the textfile is no problem, but I get unexpected trailing white space characters when I write values from a splitted string.

Example:

```
$entry = "keyword1,keyword2"
$wordArgs = ''
$keywords = $entry.split(',') # array of single keywords
foreach ($keyword in $keywords) {
        if ($keyword -ne "") {
            $wordArgs += "`n-Keywords-={0}" -f $keyword.trim() # delete keyword if present
            $wordArgs += "`n-Keywords+={0}" -f $keyword.trim() # add keyword
        }
}
```

When this string is written to the textfile, I get this result:

```
-Keywords-=keyword1 
-Keywords+=keyword1 
-Keywords-=keyword2 
-Keywords+=keyword2
```

There is a trailing white space after every keyword (end of the line).

Changing the code makes no difference:

```
$entry = "keyword1,keyword2"
$wordArgs = ''
$keywords = $entry.split(',') # array of single keywords
foreach ($keyword in $keywords) {
        $keyword = $keyword.trim() 
        if ($keyword -ne "") {
            $wordArgs += "`n-Keywords-=" + $keyword
            $wordArgs += "`n-Keywords+=" + $keyword
        }
}
```

I get a $keyword.length of 8 for the trimed variable-value (the number of characters of the keyword WITHOUT a trailing white space). So the value is correct, but the textfile-entry is not.

The code

```
$exifArgs = "-filename=$($fileData.TargetFile)" # target-file
$ExifArgs += "`n-make={0}" -f $fileData.make # camera maker
$ExifArgs += "`n-model={0}" -f $fileData.model # camera model
```

gives me this entry in the textfile:

```
-filename=P:\atest\exif\temp\testrenamed\nikon\2003\20031130-133800_00001.nef
-make=NIKON
-model=E5000
```

with no trailing white space in all three lines.

I have no idea why I get the additional trailing white spaces. Maybe the splitting of the string causes this effect?

How can I get rid of the trailing white spaces

Peace

Edit:

Sorry, I did not mention how the string is written to the textfile:

```
$exifArgs = "-filename=$($fileData.TargetFile)" # target-file
$ExifArgs += "`n-make={0}" -f $fileData.make # camera maker
$ExifArgs += "`n-model={0}" -f $fileData.model # camera model

$entry = "keyword1,keyword2"
$wordArgs = ''
$keywords = $entry.split(',') # array of single keywords
foreach ($keyword in $keywords) {
        $keyword = $keyword.trim() 
        if ($keyword -ne "") {
            $wordArgs += "`n-Keywords-=" + $keyword
            $wordArgs += "`n-Keywords+=" + $keyword
        }
}

$exifArgs += $wordArgs # all keywords
$exifArgs += "`n$($fileData.sourcefile)"
$exifArgs += "`n-execute`n" # end of EXIFTOOL-command-set

$ExifArgs | Out-File $OutputArgsFile - Append # update EXIFTOOL-argsfile
```

This code is not optimized becausee it is in development-state.

[SOLVED:]

(I cannot comment because of my current user-level, so I use the EDIT-function:)

The problem is the split-command. The elements of the array (result of the split-command) have all the expected values. When concatenating the trimmed array-elements to a string by using

```
$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords-=" + $keyword
$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords+=" + $keyword

#or

$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords-={0}" -f $keyword.trim()
$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords+={0}" -f $keyword.trim()
```

POWERSHELL adds the white-space after every keyword for any reason.

When splitting the source-string by using a simple regex

```
$keywords = [regex]::split($entry, ',')
```

the array-elements (keywords) are concatenated correctly as expected when coding

```
$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords-=" + $keyword
$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords+=" + $keyword

#or

$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords-={0}" -f $keyword.trim()
$wordArgs += "`n-Keywords+={0}" -f $keyword.trim()
```

No additional white-space is written to the textfile.

I have tested exporting to a textfile by using two different export-commands with different encodings (UTF8, UTF-16, ...).

```
# default encoding
$ExifArgs | Out-File $OutputArgsFile - Append # update EXIFTOOL-argsfile

$ExifArgs | Add-Content $OutputArgsFile # update EXIFTOOL-argsfile
```

Both files look fine if the splitting had been done with regex.

Thank you for helping me to find this solution.

Peace

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't explain the symptom. In memory, the string ends up _without_ a trailing space on each line. How are you writing it to a file?

Comment: The file-writing code doesn't explain your symptom either, but there is one notable caveat: in _Windows PowerShell_, `Out-File [-Append]` writes "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) encoded data to the file, in the case of `-Append` irrespective of a preexisting file's character encoding (In PowerShell (Core) 7+, (BOM-less) UTF-8 is used). Thus, if the output file appended to uses a different encoding, the file gets corrupted.

Comment: Note that you can always post an _answer_ to _your own_ questions, irrespective of reputation level. However, I'm also mystified by your resolution, because  `[regex]::split('a,b,c', ',')` behaves the same as `'a,b,c'.Split(',')` Also note that in lieu of `[regex]::split('a,b,c', ',')` you can do `'a,b,c' -split ','`, which is equivalent (RHS is a regex too).